# Can not transform function in class in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

Sorry for my poor knowledge of classes in Django, I have written my first training project via functions and now can not get it how to transform some functions in Classes.

I had this function which works:

```
@login_required
def topic(request, topic_slug):
    """Выводит одну тему и все её записи."""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=topic_slug)
    Проверка того, что тема принадлежит текущему пользователю
    check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Now could not transform it in to Class for the same work. I have this:

```
    class ShowTopic(DetailView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'learning_logs/topic.html'
    context_object_name = 'topic'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'topic_slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Topic.objects.filter(topic__slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])
```

For logging required I know I should add the mixin later, but right now I have error: Cannot resolve keyword 'topic' into field. Choices are: date_added, entry, id, owner, owner_id, public, slug, text
And could not understand how can I insert entries here? Could somebody give me advice please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: change this `return Topic.objects.filter(topic__slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])` to `return Topic.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])`

Comment: In your `get_queryset` method , try `return Topic.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])`, because `topic__slug` on wich you apply the filter does not exist in the `Topic` model.

Comment: Thanks it works! But now I should understand how to add one more variable "entries"